# Typescript Map with different type depending on key

Tags: typescript

I have a Map with different values depending on then key, like

```
const m = new Map()

map.set(LE_CONST_NAMES, {names: ['jhon', 'pietro']})
map.set(LE_CONST_MAMA, ['unbelievable', 'yes', {who: 'are'}])
map.set(LE_CONST_OTHER, {status: 'no status'})
```

etc...

They are all different types, and when I want to access I have to cast

```
type Name = {names: string[]}
type Status = {status: 'no status' | 'maybe status'}

const names = map.get(LE_CONST_NAMES) as Name
const theOthers = map.get(LE_CONST_OTHER) as Status
```

I want to type my const `m` so that I don't need to cast every time

```
const m = new Map<string, Name | Status | Mama | AllTheOther40SOmethingTypes>()
```

don't really solve anything, so I was thinking something like:

```
type MyKeyedMap = Omit<typeof Map, 'get'> & {
  get: <Key>(key: Key extends SomeTypescriptMagicProbablyInvolvingInfer === typeof LE_CONST_NAMES ? Name : Key === typeof LE_CONST_OTHER ? Status : etc...  ) => MoreMagic
}
```

Something like this... so I can do this:

```
const names = map.get(LE_CONST_NAMES) // automatically identifies as Name
const theOthers = map.get(LE_CONST_OTHER) // automatically identifies as Status
```

Comment: Then that's not a map. Maps are supposed to be homogenous. If you know the keys and types ahead of time, use a regular object.

Comment: @kelly sounds reasonable... Do you know a way to do as described in the question? For the sake of science and knowledge

Comment: You could extend the Map class and hack the types into the `get` method (override)